# Best way to select files based on file extension (writing in r)

Tags: r

How do I select files based on file extension (writing in r)? 
Tried

```
list.files (pattern = ".lvm$")
```

in order to select lvm files- no joy

Comment: And what about that didn't work? I don't know what you mean by "no joy" and how that relates to the output you got vs the output you expected

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the "." (as `\\.`).  An unescaped "." means "every character except a new line" in regex.

There's also `fs::dir_ls` as

```
fs::dir_ls(data directory, regexp = "\\.lvm$")
```